# vs2008: create and consume xml files

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008

what is the best way to create and consume xml files in vs2008? I am not sure if LINQ could be used? are there any good tutorials out there for vs2008 xml?

Comment: VS2008 is an IDE, which can be used to develop in HTML/JS, C++, .NET (C# or VB), XSLT... what exactly are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... I would like to read Database records, create xml file, send it to a vendor, get response from vendor, process it and save some of the results to different xml files. 

What is the best way of doing it in .net?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using office documents, the Open Office XML SDK can be used to manipulate office documents.

[http://openxmldevelloper.org/default.aspx](http://openxmldeveloper.org/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As @Pavel Minaev said, VS2008 is an IDE.  Unless we're both reading the question wrong, what you need to be asking is "what is the best way to create and consume XML files in .Net".

That said, XML is so pervasive in .Net that there is no quick and easy answer for this.  There are just too many options to choose from to select a single best option.  It all depends on what you're doing.  However, here are a few places to start.  Documentation for all of these can be found in the MSDN library.

- The [System.Data.DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) and [System.Data.DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx)'s .ReadXml and .WriteXml functions are one easy method.
- Research the [System.XML namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.aspx) in the MSDN library, paying particular attention to the XmlDocument class, and the XmlReader and XmlWriter classes
- Finally, [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx) has the ability to persist objects as XML documents and read them back into objects from an XML file.
- [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is certainly an option

And finally, here's an article for beginners:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/dot-net-xml

**Edit - added**

I'm assuming you don't mean something as simple as opening an XML document in Visual Studio, editing it like a text document, and saving it, which can, of course, be done just like editing any code or text file....